# Как переопределить адрес ссылки навигации в WP?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

По умолчанию в WP часть урла при постраничной навигации такая: /page/2/
Мне нужно (точнее SEO-шнику), чтобы эта часть выводилась так: /page-2/
Как можно это сделать?

Comment: Гнать в шею таких сеошниегов. А ВП лучше не трогать формирование УРЛов

Comment: @SeVlad вот то же самое хотел написать. Алхимики нашего времени...

Comment: @KAGGDesign не скажи.. алхимики много больше полезного принесли и изобрели . :)